# How to duplicate specific table content(given condition) into a new database table using php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

How to duplicate specific table content(given condition) into a new database table using php codeigniter ?

For example, I should get from db job table the following:

1. job_id, job_title, job_description, client_id provided that the job was already awarded by client to provider (i.e. "status"=="Awarded") 
   NOTE: I should be able to completely "copy/duplicate" these entries to avoid missing link if ever the specific job was later on deleted by client
2. provider_id , proposal_id from db job_proposal table (again, I think condition here is status==approved)

and then add NEW fields that are nowhere in the existing tables in my db..

I would appreciate any help.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE 'new_table_name' LIKE 'your_table_name';
```

Then

```
INSERT INTO New_table SELECT * FROM Old_table1,Old_table2 GROUP BY ID;
```

This will create a new table with all the datas.This command is used as a backup for the tables.

**NOTE**: If the second table doesn't have the same strucutre, u hv to first create the necessary columns, and then get the backup of the datas from the second table

Comment: the data in 1. I wrote should come from job table while data in 2. should come from job_proposal table.. also, not all contents should be copied, only those that correspond to that of awarded status

Comment: is it right to add CREATE TABLE 'deal' LIKE 'job, job_proposal'; in a new function I will make which I will name create_deal() ?

Comment: It shud be like the updated answer, then only datas from the old table will get inserted into the new one

Comment: You can only backup both the tables if they have the same structure...so u can give the two table names in the INSERT statement.look at the edited answer

Comment: where should I put it? I mean

Comment: If both the tables structures are not same, then first back up the first table, then insert the columns of the old tables into new one, and then backup the second table accordingly

Comment: Right now i m leaving from my office, i will ping u in an hour

Comment: In the mean while, try this http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php

Comment: thank you sir. I will wait for you.. I will try to continue different ways for now.. but I will really need your help. (bow)